# how to add horizontal line in nativescript-angular html file

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I tried "hr" tag in component html file in nativescript-angular. But it doesn't shown horizontal line in simulator. (tested with ios simulator)

```
  <StackLayout>
     hr>
     <Label horizontalAlignment="left" textWrap="true" text="Description" class="description-text"></Label>
     </StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Shouldn't that `hr` go as a class inside the `StackLayout`?

Like `<StackLayout class="hr-light">...`

[Reference](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/theme#dividers)

Comment: Note: the CSS class `hr-light` is part of `nativescript-theme` plugin

Comment: Another option to create lines is to simply use CSS property `border` https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling#supported-css-properties

Answer (score 1):

```html
<Label class="line" text="About"></Label>
```

// To give the bottom border

```css
.about-heading{
    font-size: 19;
    padding: 5 18;
    border-color: #3BEC9C;
    border-width: 0 0 2 0;
}
```

// To give the top border

```css
.about-heading{
    font-size: 19;
    padding: 5 18;
    border-color: #3BEC9C;
    border-width: 2 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: This should be the recommended answer. For the sake of performance, using one StackLayout (equates to one native container) for a horizontal line, is not efficient.